# When is the devicetree parsed to populate the device list on arm64 architecture?

Tags: boot, drivers, devices, device-tree

This question comes from my attempts to understand how a built-in `platform device` driver is initialized at boot time.

I am using an embedded linux distro (Yocto) on a SoC (ARM + FPGA). The device driver is written for a `platform device` and the IP can be found in the device tree, described as platform device. The "compatible" property matches with the C driver, all good so far.

Quoting the kernel docs for platform devices [[1]](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/devicetree/usage-model.html),

> It is generally assumed that any node with a ‘compatible’ property represents a device of some kind, and second, it can be assumed that any node at the root of the tree is either directly attached to the processor bus, or is a miscellaneous system device that cannot be described any other way. **For each of these nodes, Linux allocates and registers a platform_device, which in turn may get bound to a platform_driver.**

but also

> ### 2.4 Device population
>
> After the board has been identified, and after the early configuration data has been parsed, then kernel initialization can proceed in the
> normal way. [...] This is also when machine-specific setup hooks willget called, like the machine_desc .init_early(), .init_irq() and .init_machine() hooks on ARM.
>
> [...]
>
> The most interesting hook in the DT context is .init_machine() which is primarily responsible for populating the Linux device model with data about the platform

and eventually (following the docs example with Tegra board)

> At .init_machine() time, Tegra board support code will need to look at this DT and decide which nodes to create platform_devices for

And sure enough, looking into `arch/arm` [[2](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L944)] I can find the `init_machine` function that "looks" into the device tree. However, this function does not exist for arm64 architecture. The `machine_desc` struct [only exists for arm arch](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/machine_desc).

Browsing the source code I was able to locate some operations on the device tree, none of them easy to understand, happening in setup_machine_fdt [[4](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/devtree.c#L211)] which calls `early_dt_scan` but they **don't seem to populate the devices**:

```
    /* Retrieve various information from the /chosen node */
    rc = of_scan_flat_dt(early_init_dt_scan_chosen, boot_command_line);

    /* Initialize {size,address}-cells info */
    of_scan_flat_dt(early_init_dt_scan_root, NULL);

    /* Setup memory, calling early_init_dt_add_memory_arch */
    of_scan_flat_dt(early_init_dt_scan_memory, NULL);
```

The trouble here is that if I keep following the boot process I arrive at `do_basic_setup` which in turns calls `driver init`, `bus_init`,`platform_bus_init` and eventually `of_core_init`.

I had some hopes with the last one, which creates a kset called "devicetree". However I don't understand if the tree is actually parsed here.

After this, the `initcalls` are called, meaning that the driver initialization will happen, but where was the DT parsing involved here? Where was the "compatible" property actually used? Again from the docs:

> The trick is that the kernel starts at the root of the tree and looks for nodes that have a ‘compatible’ property. First, it is generally assumed that any node with a ‘compatible’ property represents a device of some kind, and second, it can be assumed that any node at the root of the tree is either directly attached to the processor bus, or is a miscellaneous system device that cannot be described any other way. For each of these nodes, **Linux allocates and registers a platform_device, which in turn may get bound to a platform_drive.**

The "bound to platform drive" part is done by the initcall defined by the driver code, what I don't understand is the "allocates and registers a platform device".

[1] [Linux and the Device Tree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/devicetree/usage-model.html)

[2]  [init_machine arm](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L944)

[3]  [machine_desc search on bootlin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/machine_desc)

[4]  [setup_machine_fdt arm64](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/devtree.c#L211)